# Any ideas on how to make a partitioner that will not break a device with a bash program?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, system-installation

So, I am trying to create a bash program that can be grabbed from my website that will do all of the functions necessary to install Arch without putting in all of the work. I need it to be able to erase disks, create/delete partitions, and to install programs. The one that I am having trouble with is erasing disks and creating/deleting partitions safely. How can I do this without bricking a device?

On another question on this resource (https://superuser.com/questions/332252/how-to-create-and-format-a-partition-using-a-bash-script)

I saw this code:

```
# to create the partitions programatically (rather than manually)
# we're going to simulate the manual input to fdisk
# The sed script strips off all the comments so that we can 
# document what we're doing in-line with the actual commands
# Note that a blank line (commented as "defualt" will send a empty
# line terminated with a newline to take the fdisk default.
sed -e 's/\s*\([\+0-9a-zA-Z]*\).*/\1/' << EOF | fdisk ${TGTDEV}
  o # clear the in memory partition table
  n # new partition
  p # primary partition
  1 # partition number 1
    # default - start at beginning of disk 
  +100M # 100 MB boot parttion
  n # new partition
  p # primary partition
  2 # partion number 2
    # default, start immediately after preceding partition
    # default, extend partition to end of disk
  a # make a partition bootable
  1 # bootable partition is partition 1 -- /dev/sda1
  p # print the in-memory partition table
  w # write the partition table
  q # and we're done
EOF
```

Can someone tell me if a user has to specify variables? I would like the program to be able to run all of the partitioning commands to create ease for the user. Also, is this safe?

Comment: you are asking two separate, unrelated questions ... please post them separately ... this site is not a forum

Comment: I'm not sure what your concern wrt. bricking a device is. Partitioning programs only write data on the disk. Data that the OS treats a bit specially, but as far as the disk is concerned, data it is. What you can do by messing with the partition table is to make all the data on the disk essentially inaccessible. But if your intention is to put the entire disk to new use, the most that can go wrong is that the partition table doesn't meet your requirements, and you get to build a new one... Of course, if you have multiple disks, better make sure you partition the correct one.

Comment: As for "Can someone tell me if a user has to specify variables?", what variables would those be?

Comment: You don't check for errors, you assume the disk size, you create a sub-optimal partition scheme, you do not document, ... UNSAFE!!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using `sfdisk` instead of `fdisk`:

First of all, to create a gpt partition table, an EFI partition and an EXT4 partition on the disk `/dev/sda`, you would do:

```
sfdisk -X gpt /dev/sda <<EEOF 
,+500M,U,
,,L,
write   
EEOF
```

If instead of GPT you want DOS, do: `-X dos` instead of `-X gpt`

This will create a 500mb EFI partition and an EXT4 partition using the rest of the space available on disk `/dev/sda`.
`U` and `V` indicate the partition type. Where `V` is an EFI partition and `U` an EXT4 partition.

If you still want to use fdisk. You will have to do something similar as before but with the chance that a warning will rice if you are overwriting an old partition table. This will require user input (which I think you don't want).

Check `man sfdisk` for partition types aliases and more info.

Something to consider: If the user doesn't have `sda` disk, this will failed. Instead I would recommend user input, this way the user can specify in wich disk he wants to install Arch.

`read -p "Name of disk to install: " disk`

then you do the same as before but instead of `sda` you use `$disk`:

`sfdisk -X gpt /dev/$disk <<EEOF`

After creating the partitions, remember to [format the partitions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide#Format_the_partitions)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the work that went into this. Do you know if this will be safe to use?

Answer (score 1):

The tool `parted` may be exactly what you need. It's the command line equivalent of `gparted`. I use it for programmatic configuration of multiple disks in a soft-RAID scenario.

First I use a helper function `pdisk`. If you just give it a device it'll print the partition table. Otherwise it'll act with the command you give it

```
pdisk() {
    local dev ="$1"
    shift
    test 0 -eq $# && set -- print
    parted "$dev" --align optimal unit MiB "$@"
}
```

And here's an example of setting a GPT partition table

```
d=/dev/sdz
pdisk "$d" --script mklabel gpt

pdisk "$d" mkpart primary fat32 1 511             # 511MB EFI
pdisk "$d" set 1 boot on
pdisk "$d" set 1 esp on

pdisk "$d" mkpart primary 511 512# 1MB Grub
pdisk "$d" set 2 bios_grub on

pdisk "$d" mkpart primary 512 $((512 + 20*1024))  # 20GB

pdisk "$d" mkpart primary $((512 + 20*1024)) 100% # Everything else
```